# Install .nupkg locally on macOS using dotnet or nuget

Tags: c#, nuget

### Question

I've got a `.nupkg` file, and I'm trying to install it locally on macOS, so that I can run a .net core application that depends on it. How do I do this?

I've installed the `dotnet` runtime, `mono` and `nuget.exe`. I've tried to look at the different `nuget install` options, tried things like `nuget install <file>.nupkg`, `nuget install -Source . <file>`, ... but nothing seems to work; they just tell me that the path is incorrect or show me the command help again. I'd expect it to say something like "installing .nupkg to ~/.nuget/packages".

I read that one of the options that Windows users have is an `Install-Package` command that they can use from Powershell, but I'm pretty sure this should be possible with just nuget as well?

### Background

I'm somewhat new to .net and .net core development.

I've compiled some .net core code in Windows that depends on a custom library, and I believe I should be able to run the resulting `.dll` file on macOS using `dotnet`. Instead, I get an error similar to the following:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (foo.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'A.B', version: '0.9.5'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/A.B.dll'
```

### Update

I think I misunderstood the purpose of the `.nupkg` files; I now think they're only used during development, and not for running the code (the dependencies for running the code seem to be packaged as `.dll`s, as the  error message above says).

I solved the error above by *publishing* the project (`dotnet publish`), and then I can run the resulting `.dll` using `dotnet ./path/to/publish/foo.dll`; the dependencies end up being copied into the `publish` folder.

I still had issues figuring out how to install the `.nupkg`s for development, so I'm grateful for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
dotnet add package A.B -s "<here_your_path_to_nupkg>"
```

Or add local source like

```
nuget sources add -name FeedName -Source "<here_your_path_to_nupkg>"
```

then

```
dotnet add package A.B -s FeedName
```

Comment: The first command worked when passing in the path to the folder containing the `.nupkg`. The path must *not* contain spaces, even if correctly escaped in your shell. I can now use `dotnet run` from within the source code directory to run the code from the project source code directory. It doesn't look like this fixes my issue when trying to run the code with `dotnet`, but I think that's because I just "built" the code in Release mode, rather than "publish"ing it.